# How to count different files in azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I came across a problem of counting different file types in Azure blob container. There is a folder which contains different file types like csv, json, binary. What is the simplest way to show count of each file type ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest (and I believe the only) way to do it would be to list the blobs in that folder. You will get the names of the blobs as part of the listing. You can then group them based on the file extension.

If you search for it, you will find a lot of code examples showing how list the blobs in a blob container or a virtual folder.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, I was hoping it can be done without much coding.